# Unity Particle System collision detection problem

Tags: collision-detection, unity, particles

I'm using Unity 3.5.5f3 wich has the Shuriken particle system.

I've made a blood particle system based on Unity's demos. (Exploding paint [Blood])
The blood is flowing and when it collides with a Plane Transform wich I've created a small pool of blood spawns as a Collision Sub Emitter.

[image: Collision and Sub Emitter]

My main problem is that when I want to add another object to collide it just doesn't want to work. When I create a cube, and set it as a collision plane the collision will only occur at the half of the cube.

[image: Collision occurs at half of the cube]

[image: Another picture]

I want this to happen: When it reaches the cube's surface the sub emmiter activates, and when the surface is horizontal it appears horizontally, and if it's vertical then vertically. Now it just appears horizontally everytime like in the picture.

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research I've come to the conclusion that I can't do it with Particle System collision, because it can only collide with planes. To create an effect like I've described, a solution for it is Texture Decals.

Comment: What if you add planes that are rotated to form a bounding box cube?

Comment: I've already tried that. No matter how small I resize them it thinks it's big, so they collide outside of the box's range.